# React - .map inside ternary (jsx)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm a bit stuck with this. I need to create a Dropdown from a specific dataSource (array) with .map, but in case the ternary condition is true, need the options from dataSource + another option.

I tried this, but it's not rendering

```
         <Dropdown
          key={dataSource}
          type="form"
          label=""
          primary="Select..."
          valid={validation.dataSource.isValid}
          message={validation.dataSource.message}
          className="query-type__datasource-dropdown"
          disabled={mode === 'view' || (dataSource === 'xde' && !showXDE)}
          onChange={(e, value) => { onChangeDatasource(value) }}

          (showXDE || dataSource === 'xde') ?
          {dataSources.map(dataSourceItem => {
            <DropdownItem
              key={dataSourceItem.id}
              value={dataSourceItem.id}
              primary={dataSourceItem.description}
              selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
            />
          })}
          <DropdownItem
            key="xde"
            value="xde"
            primary="XDE"
            selected={dataSource === 'xde'}
            />
          :
          {dataSources.map(dataSourceItem => {
            <DropdownItem
              key={dataSourceItem.id}
              value={dataSourceItem.id}
              primary={dataSourceItem.description}
              selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
            />
          })}
         </Dropdown>
```

EDIT: Added rest of the Dropdown info for references

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
      {showXDE || dataSource === "xde" ? (
        <>
          {dataSources.map((dataSourceItem) => (
            <DropdownItem
              key={dataSourceItem.id}
              value={dataSourceItem.id}
              primary={dataSourceItem.description}
              selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
            />
          ))}
          <DropdownItem
            key="xde"
            value="xde"
            primary="XDE"
            selected={dataSource === "xde"}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        dataSources.map((dataSourceItem) => (
          <DropdownItem
            key={dataSourceItem.id}
            value={dataSourceItem.id}
            primary={dataSourceItem.description}
            selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
          />
        ))
      )}
```

The first issue with your code is that your map functions don't actually return anything and thus won't render what's inside them. By dropping the curly braces, you implicitly add a return statement.

The other issue is there has to be a parent to the two elements inside your first ternary condition. i.e you cannot have two siblings without a parent, which is what you tried to do. Adding `<>...</>` rectifies that problem. `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` is commonly used. You could also add `<div>...</div>`, but that would depend on your styling.

Comment: Hi, this is almost right, but in case ternary is true, it shows the options but is not possible to select any of them. The console error "Invalid prop 'children' of type 'object' supplied to 'Dropdown', expected an array"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not returning components from the `map`:

```
(showXDE || dataSource === 'xde') ?
   {dataSources.map(dataSourceItem => {
     return(
       <DropdownItem
        key={dataSourceItem.id}
        value={dataSourceItem.id}
        primary={dataSourceItem.description}
        selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
       />
     )
    })}
    <DropdownItem
      key="xde"
      value="xde"
      primary="XDE"
      selected={dataSource === 'xde'}
     />
     :
     {dataSources.map(dataSourceItem => {
       return (
         <DropdownItem
          key={dataSourceItem.id}
          value={dataSourceItem.id}
          primary={dataSourceItem.description}
          selected={dataSource === dataSourceItem.id}
         />
       )
      })}
```

Comment: There are other problems with the code besides not returning from `map`s.